# $_POST within the class

Tags: php, class, post

I've got a class Posts which has public function displayPosts:

```
   public function displayPosts($numberOf = 50){
        $result = $this->mysqlResult($this->id);
        $i = 1;
        while ($post = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            $added = new Time;
            $elapsed = $added->displayElapsedSignificant($post->data);
            echo "
            <h1>$post->title</h1> 
            <i>$elapsed</i>
            <p>$post->text</p>
            <h3>...komentarze...</h3>";
            $this->displayComments($post->id);
            "<hr />";
            if($i == $numberOf) break;
            else $i++;
        }               
    }
```

And the private function displayComments:

```
private function displayComments($id){
    $postComments = new Comments;
    switch($this->getElement($id, "comment_type")){
        case 1:
            if($_POST) {
              echo addSecurity($_POST['comment']);  
            }
            else {
              echo '
              Zostaw komentarz:
                <form action="#" method="post">
                <textarea id="comment"></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value=" Dodaj komentarz " />
                </form>
                ';                      
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            //kod dla fb
            break;
        case 3:
            //kod dla obu
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the form doesn't work: the $_POST is always empty. Any solution?

Comment: Are you using this `displayComments()` function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `name` attribute for form values to be send to server - like this:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
```

`$_POST` is filled with `name` (not `id`) attributes as keys and values as values :)